# Calculating frequency distribution of a collection with .Net/C#

Tags: .net, collections, frequency-distribution

Is there a fast/simple way to calculate the frequency distribution of a .Net collection using Linq or otherwise?

For example: An arbitrarily long List contains many repetitions. What's a clever way of walking the list and counting/tracking repetitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a hashmap and either use the value as the key and increment the value, or pick a bucket size (bucket 1 = 1 - 10, bucket 2 = 11 - 20, etc), and increment each bucket by the value.

Then you can go through and determine the frequencies.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to find duplicate items in a list is to group it, like this:

```
var dups = list.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any());
```

(Writing `Skip(1).Any()` should be faster than (Count() > 1) because it won't have to traverse more than two items from each group.  However, the difference is probably negligible unless `list`'s enumerator is slow)

Answer (score 1):

The [C5 generic collections library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5) has a `HashBag` implementation that accepts duplicates by counting. The following pseudo-code would get you what you're looking for:

```
var hash = new HashBag();
hash.AddAll(list);
var mults = hash.ItemMultiplicities();
```

(where `K` is the type of the items in your list) `mults` will then contain an `IDictionary<K,int>` where the list item is the key and the multiplicity is the value.

Comment: i didn't use C5 but ended up writing my own process based on a similar idea: Dictionary<string, int>